# getUserMedia undefined when i use ip:port

Tags: javascript

I’d like to know why getUserMedia is undefined when I use IP:port, in localhost:port it’s works pretty well

Any ideia ?

My tests is in js pure running watch-http-server to up a local server , but if I use other http server for exemple lite-server I had the same problema

The problem is here

I use Chrome and Firefox

const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: false, video: true });

localhost ok
ip cant finds navigator.me****

EDIT

/*****************************************************************************/

This is the code on github
https://github.com/VictorBarbosa/stackoverflowhelp

just run npm install and npm run

after try on localhost and after with ip

Comment: welcome to SO ! Disclosing your browser name and version would probably be helpful for others to help. If possible, you should attach minimal test code sot hat people car reproduce your issue and test their proposal.

Comment: If you are using iOS and Safari, that's probably because of the luck of HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia):

> getUserMedia() is a powerful feature which can only be used in secure contexts; in insecure contexts, navigator.mediaDevices is undefined, preventing access to getUserMedia(). A secure context is, in short, a page loaded using HTTPS or the file:/// URL scheme, or a page loaded from localhost.

So it works when you use `localhost` because that is considered a secure context, but some arbitrary IP address isn't unless you use HTTPS too.